# Gtk : Make a pixbuf cellrenderer editable

Tags: haskell, combobox, treeview, gtk, gtk2hs

I want to make a combobox of pictures inside of a treeview cell (the cell must render the selected picture)

I tried these solutions :

1. Make a `cellRendererComboNew` in the column. The cells are editable but the combobox render only `Strings`!
2. I used the `editingStarted` signal to detect the edition of the cell and create a combobox with pictures in this cell. It Works fine but the cell doesn't render a picture!
3. I tryed to make a `cellRendererPixbufNew` in the column and make these cells editable (clickable,selectable) and use the `editingStarted` signal the same way as previously. But pixbuf cells are not editable!
4. I tryed to change the `cellMode` property of the cells with
   `set render [ cellMode:= CellRendererModeActivatable ]` to make the signal `editingStarted` to be emitted when clicking on the cell. But it doesn't work!

My questions are :

- Is it possible to make a pixbuf cell renderer editable? And what is the correct way to do it?
- Is it possible to detect the left click on a treeview cell and replace the widget inside this cell like with `editingStarted` ?
- Do you have an example in Haskell? Python? or any language?

Best Regards.